# CSS rotation along a specified side of a <div> element

Tags: css, html

I have one problem regarding rotating the `<div>` in html page. I have used -

```
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg)
```

But this property is rotating the `<div>` along some axis.(couldnt get that). But i want to rotate the `<div>` along its bottom side.(here, my div is a square-box). Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sounds like [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin) is what you're looking for.

> The `transform-origin` CSS property lets you modify the origin for transformations of an element. For example, the transform-origin of the rotate() function is the centre of rotation. (This property is applied by first translating the element by the negated value of the property, then applying the element's transform, then translating by the property value.)

so you should end up with something like this:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: center bottom;
/*transform-origin: 50% 100%;    alternative using percentages */
```

Comment: yes. its working fine. Thanks oezi. Working for me -

-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);-moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;

which will rotate it along right-bottom point.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this properties

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: center bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give X% and Y% as tranform-origin

For example this will gone rotate div along `bottom-left` corner

```
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
```

[image]

This one gone rotate along top right corner

```
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
```

[image]

This one gone rotate along bottom right corner

```
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

[image]

and so on ...by default its 50%,50%

```
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

[image]